# Trouble with Pandas and Plotly, script keeps loading old big file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Currently I am trying to plot multiple big csv files (up to 100 million records each file).

I want to plot all rows of two specific columns even if the files have got more columns.
The csv files should be plotted in a single figure.

For this I found a [perfect example](https://plotly.com/python/plot-data-from-csv/) and tried it out. First I wanted to read one file from my disk which is 3gb big. As I realized it will take too long I CTRL+C the terminal to stop.
Then I wanted to test the script from the website, but as I run the modified script it keeps processing the old file. I tried a lot of things like gc.collect() to clear the memory or searching for **pycache** , but nothing works.

I realized as soon "import plotly.express as px" is in my code I can't do anything but wait for processing the 3gb file which would take me some years I guess.

Comment: you can load file then save each column separately with its name then load each two columns you want  and use ```pd.concat```

Comment: do you know the name or index of these specific columns? if so, you can use ```usecols``` parameter of ```pd.read_csv()``` to read only those two cols into memory instead of reading the whole file. As a next step, if you needing to load new DFs that contain the specific columns again in the future, you may want to consider converting them to the Parquet file format using the ```to_parquet()```

Comment: What happens if you restart your machine, is the problem still persistent?

Comment: My program run through another python file for whatever reason. After deleting that file it works. Now my program crashes and my system reboots when passing the big 2gb file to plot. I am using dask. I guess I have not that much RAM.